# Use nested container as IContext in Lambda function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap, structuremap4

I have a ASP.Net MVC application set up with Structuremap and `StructuremapDependencyScope` serving up a nested container for each request.

I would like to be able to build up a list and have StructureMap return that list, for as long as the custom lifecycle is valid.

I have the following in a Structuremap `Registry`:

```
For<List<Cat>>()
    .Use(x => x.GetInstance<CatlistBuilder>().Build())
    .LifecycleIs<NineLifesLifecyle>();
```

This works great, the list `List<Cat>` is built only once until the lifecycle expires.

However, the instance of `CatlistBuilder` (and all the other dependencies it needs) is not disposed at the end of the request. I suspect the reason is the custom lifecycle - since the configuration uses a custom lifecycle, the `IContext` passed into the lambda function seems to be the root container. If I remove the custom lifecycle, the current nested container is used.

**Is it possible to have the nested container provide the `CatlistBuilder` class, and still use a custom lifecycle for the result?**

The only workaround I could come up with was to use

```
.Use(x => StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetInstance<CatlistBuilder>().Build())
```

but that does not seem correct.